# Does every finite dimensional algebra contains a semisimple subalgebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-rings

As in title - does every finite dimensional algebra over field K contains a semisimple (or semiprime, as in finite dimension it is the same) subalgebra?
Due to coronavirus I dont have my notes from last semester when I had such things.

I want to prove that if H is finite nonabelian group, the group ring $CH$ (where C is field of complex numbers) then it contains a subalgebra isomorphic to matrices over C of size 2.

It is trivial if CH is semisimple from Artin-Wiederburn Theorem. So I have to know if it contains semisimple subalgebra to use that Theorem.

Thanks in advance for writing "Yes/No".

Comment: Okay, unimportant. Every group ring over complex fields and finite group is semisimple. Sorry for question.

Comment: No finite group algebra $\mathbb{C}H$ has a subalgebra $A$ isomorphic to $M_2(\mathbb{C})$. If it did, then the restriction of the trivial $\mathbb{C}H$-module to $A$ would be a one-dimensional module for $A$, but $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ has no one-dimensional modules. (This assumes you're using the standard definition of subalgebra in representation theory, where a subalgebra must contain $1$.)

Comment: @JeremyRickard hmm. You are wrong or my professor is wrong. I believe he is right.

Comment: It is pretty clear that they are both right, given the context. The point is that a subalgebra must usually include $1$. But when discussing Artin-Wedderburn, the direct factors clearly do not contain $1$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft thank You Tobias! Well said.